# How can I run a Clockwork job manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork

Title says it all really.

Is it possible to run Clockwork jobs manually? E.g. if I have a `clock.rb` file

```
module Clockwork
  every(15.minutes, 'api.sync_shifts') do
    Shift.sync
  end

  on(:after_run) do |event, t|
    REDIS.hset("clockwork:last_run", event.job, t)
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to call something like `Clockwork.run('api.sync_shifts')`.

I looked through the clockwork source and didn't see anything useful. Obviously, I can run, in this example, the `Shift.sync` method manually, but then I'd lose my after_run/before_run callbacks that I'm using to monitor my job statuses.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Clockwork, but it seems you need to add a level of abstraction and make the methods you need available via Clockwork or whatever other interface you wish to call the method from.  Could you wrap `Shift.sync` in a method that also calls `REDIS.hset`, or is that command part of the Clockwork DSL?

Comment: Maybe extract your events into separate scripts which are run from the clockwork file.

Comment: I was hoping Clockwork itself would be my level of abstraction but does look like I need to wrap it all one layer up. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

This is the [relevant method](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork/blob/master/lib/clockwork/manager.rb#L70) in the clockwork gem that handles callbacks and runs configured events:

```
def tick(t=Time.now)
  if (fire_callbacks(:before_tick))
    events = events_to_run(t)
    events.each do |event|
      if (fire_callbacks(:before_run, event, t))
        event.run(t)
        fire_callbacks(:after_run, event, t)
      end
    end
  end
  fire_callbacks(:after_tick)
  events
end
```

This method loads all events that should run at the current time (returned from the `events_to_run` method). It iterates over all events in `events_to_run` and fires callbacks and runs the `event`.

To be able to run individual events and still have all callbacks fired, this method would need to change to something like this:

```
def tick(t=Time.now)
  if (fire_callbacks(:before_tick))
    events = events_to_run(t)
    events.each do |event|
      run_event_with_callbacks(event)
    end
  end
  fire_callbacks(:after_tick)
  events
end

def run_event_with_callbacks(event)
  if (fire_callbacks(:before_run, event, t))
    event.run(t)
      fire_callbacks(:after_run, event, t)
    end
  end
end
```

That would allow running individual events with firing callbacks. Furthermore, you would need a method to load an individual event. Perhaps something like this:

```
def load_event(job)
  # finds only the first event when there are multiple 
  # events registered for the same job
  @events.find { |event| event.job == job }
end
```

But since the events are registered in a `Manager`, you would need an instance of a manager which is correctly initialized with all events defined in the config.

To keep a long story short: This is not possible at the moment and it would need many changes to the structure of the code to make that possible.

Comment: I wish there was the better answer, but this is the answer. Thanks!